# C# interface with properties and implementing class

Tags: c#, properties

I want to put Properties in the interface.
My problem if I do:

```
class ClassA: IClassA
{
    public string Id{ get; private set; }
```

Interface:

```
public interface IClassA
{
    string Id{ get; }
}
```

This does not compile, from one hand, i want to enforce implementing classes to have the property, So i did not put "set" in the interface, when i try to compile i get:

> ```
> .ClassA.set' is not public.
> ```

Comment: I just copied your code into a new Visual Studio project and it compiles perfectly.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Possible you're missing a closing } in the interface?

Comment: It compiles perfectly for me too

Comment: `.ClassA.set` - there is no mention of "Id" in this error message - maybe it relates to a different part in your code?

Comment: Hey, code was fine, a mistake was confusing me, fixed the code, this post can be deleted

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Your interface specifies a property getter only, so implementers are only required to specify the getter. Whether they specify a setter, and whether the setter is public or private does not matter. All 3 of these should be valid for the IClassA as specified.

```
class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public string Id { get; }
}

class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean "property getter"?

Comment: @Todd: sorry - took the liberty to edit appropriately

Comment: NP, I was obviously typing too fast. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  using System;

  internal class ClassA : IClassA
  {
    public ClassA(string id)
    {
      this.Id = id;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
  }

  public interface IClassA
  {
      string Id{ get; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var a = new ClassA("Test");

      Console.WriteLine(a.Id);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

If you compiler is having problems, check the other parts of your code or post the complete error message including the line of code.